# Other abscissa than $y = 0$?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Circle contains three vertices whose coordinates are (0,6) , (0,10) and (8,0). Abscissa of second vertex in which given circle passes through x-axis, is equal to?
I do not even understand the text of this task. I always thought that abscissa is only y = 0. Sorry for my misknowledge, can someone explain me true meaning of abscissa, and how it can be applied on this task? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have a circle. It passes through two points on the $y$-axis --- namely $(0, 6), (0, 10)$ --- and two points on the $x$-axis, $(8, 0)$ and $(q, 0)$. But you don't yet know $q$.

The question asks you to find $q$, which is the abcissa of the second point at which the circle intersects the $x$-axis. Note that at this mystery point, the $y$-coordinate is, as you expected, $0$.